# Is it possible to directly go to content of div by URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Content is displayed with the previous and next buttons, but can it be possible to show the contents of the box directly with the link?

For example:

> https://example.com/content/#/2

so can the second box be shown to the content?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {
    if ($('.active').next('.case').length) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active')
        .next('.case')
        .addClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    if ($('.active').prev('.case').length) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active')
        .prev('.case')
        .addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.case {
  display: none
}

.active {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="next">
  <h1>next</h1>
</div>
<div id="prev">
  <h1>prev</h1>
</div>
<div id="box1" class="case active">content 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="case">content 2</div>
<div id="box3" class="case">content 3</div>
```

**What have I done?**

```
if($(location).attr('hash') != null) {
        document.getElementById('box' + $(location).attr('hash').replace("#", "")).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

but it didn't work

**Update 1**

I changed:

```
if($(location).attr('hash') != null) {
        document.getElementById('box' + $(location).attr('hash').replace("#/", "")).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('box' + $(location).attr('hash').replace("#/", "")).addClass('active');
    }
```

result, it didn't work

[JSFiddle on Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/3xabt84v/)

If possible, can you guide me?

Comment: location.hash.replace("#", "") --> "/2" , document.getElementById('box/2') = null

Comment: Yes I fixed it, but now the previous and next buttons do not work.  @rckrd

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {
    if ($('.active').next('.case').length) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active')
        .next('.case')
        .addClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    if ($('.active').prev('.case').length) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active')
        .prev('.case')
        .addClass('active');
    }
  });
//var location = window.location.href
var location = 'https://example.com/content/#/3'; //for example
 if(location.split("#/")) {
    $('#box' + location.split("#/")[1]).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.case {
  display: none
}

.active {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="next">
  <h1>next</h1>
</div>
<div id="prev">
  <h1>prev</h1>
</div>
<div id="box1" class="case">content 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="case">content 2</div>
<div id="box3" class="case">content 3</div>
```